# failed to create SFTP Session

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I'm using the below code to connect to FTP server(s) for transferring files, server details are entered in postgres DB using a HTML interface and the spring integration code should take the config from the DB and rotate through the list and pull the file from a specific folder.

It try to connect then it says connected but nothing is transferred and then after couple of minutes it disconnects then tries again.

I have two branches in the DB to rotate but it also tries for the first one only.

Error of disconnect is "java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create SFTP Session"

Here is the full log.

```
2018-10-23 11:53:51.694  INFO 1940 --- [ask-scheduler-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : Connecting to cai-notes-fs.cai.ei port 21
2018-10-23 11:53:51.834  INFO 1940 --- [ask-scheduler-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : Connection established
2018-10-23 11:56:01.227  INFO 1940 --- [ask-scheduler-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : Disconnecting from cai-notes-fs.cai.ei port 21
2018-10-23 11:56:01.242 ERROR 1940 --- [ask-scheduler-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Problem occurred while synchronizing remote to local directory; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to execute on session; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create SFTP Session
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:331)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.doReceive(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.java:260)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.doReceive(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.java:65)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractFetchLimitingMessageSource.doReceive(AbstractFetchLimitingMessageSource.java:43)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractMessageSource.receive(AbstractMessageSource.java:154)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:197)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.integration.aop.AbstractMessageSourceAdvice.invoke(AbstractMessageSourceAdvice.java:43)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy121.receive(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:236)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:249)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:197)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy120.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.lambda$run$0(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:378)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:53)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:372)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to execute on session; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create SFTP Session
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:445)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:286)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create SFTP Session
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:393)
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:57)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.DelegatingSessionFactory.getSession(DelegatingSessionFactory.java:111)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.DelegatingSessionFactory.getSession(DelegatingSessionFactory.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:431)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to connect
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.connect(SftpSession.java:272)
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:388)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Session.connect: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:565)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.connect(SftpSession.java:263)
    ... 49 more

2018-10-23 11:56:11.248  INFO 1940 --- [ask-scheduler-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : Connecting to cai-notes-fs.cai.ei port 21
2018-10-23 11:56:11.414  INFO 1940 --- [ask-scheduler-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : Connection established


    //
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by Fernflower decompiler)
//
```

Here is the correct code

```
     package fefo.springframeworkftp.spring4ftpapp.configuration;

import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
import fefo.springframeworkftp.spring4ftpapp.model.Branch;
import fefo.springframeworkftp.spring4ftpapp.repository.BranchRepository;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.NullChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlows;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.Pollers;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec;
import org.springframework.integration.expression.FunctionExpression;
import org.springframework.integration.file.remote.*;
import org.springframework.integration.file.remote.aop.RotatingServerAdvice;
import org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.DelegatingSessionFactory;
import org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.integration.scheduling.PollerMetadata;
import org.springframework.integration.sftp.dsl.Sftp;
import org.springframework.integration.sftp.dsl.SftpInboundChannelAdapterSpec;
import org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.io.File;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

@Configuration
@Component
public class SFTIntegration {

    public static final String TIMEZONE_UTC = "UTC";
    public static final String TIMESTAMP_FORMAT_OF_FILES = "yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS";
    public static final String TEMPORARY_FILE_SUFFIX = ".part";
    public static final int POLLER_FIXED_PERIOD_DELAY = 5000;
    public static final int MAX_MESSAGES_PER_POLL = 100;


    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SFTIntegration.class);
    private static final String CHANNEL_INTERMEDIATE_STAGE = "intermediateChannel";

    /* pulling the server config from postgres DB*/

    private final BranchRepository branchRepository;

    @Value("${app.temp-dir}")
    private String localTempPath;

    public SFTIntegration(BranchRepository branchRepository) {
        this.branchRepository = branchRepository;
    }

    /**
     * The default poller with 5s, 100 messages, RotatingServerAdvice and transaction.
     *
     * @return default poller.
     */
    @Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
    public PollerMetadata poller(){
        return Pollers
                .fixedDelay(POLLER_FIXED_PERIOD_DELAY)
                .advice(advice())
                .maxMessagesPerPoll(MAX_MESSAGES_PER_POLL)
                .transactional()
                .get();
    }

    /**
     * The direct channel for the flow.
     *
     * @return MessageChannel
     */
    @Bean
    public MessageChannel stockIntermediateChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    /**
     * Get the files from a remote directory. Add a timestamp to the filename
     * and write them to a local temporary folder.
     *
     * @return IntegrationFlow
     */
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow fileInboundFlowFromSFTPServer(){

        final SftpInboundChannelAdapterSpec sourceSpec = Sftp.inboundAdapter(delegatingSFtpSessionFactory())
                .preserveTimestamp(true)
                .patternFilter("*.csv")
                .deleteRemoteFiles(true)
                .maxFetchSize(MAX_MESSAGES_PER_POLL)
                .remoteDirectory("/")
                .localDirectory(new File(localTempPath))
                .temporaryFileSuffix(TEMPORARY_FILE_SUFFIX)
                .localFilenameExpression(new FunctionExpression<String>(s -> {
                    final int fileTypeSepPos = s.lastIndexOf('.');
                    return DateTimeFormatter
                            .ofPattern(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT_OF_FILES)
                            .withZone(ZoneId.of(TIMEZONE_UTC))
                            .format(Instant.now())
                            + "_"
                            + s.substring(0, fileTypeSepPos)
                            + s.substring(fileTypeSepPos);
                }));

        // Poller definition
        final Consumer<SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec> stockInboundPoller = endpointConfigurer -> endpointConfigurer
                .id("stockInboundPoller")
                .autoStartup(true)
                .poller(poller());

        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(sourceSpec, stockInboundPoller)
                .transform(File.class, p -> {
                    // log step
                    LOG.info("flow=stockInboundFlowFromAFT, message=incoming file: " + p);
                    return p;
                })
                .channel(CHANNEL_INTERMEDIATE_STAGE)
                .get();

    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow stockIntermediateStageChannel() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(CHANNEL_INTERMEDIATE_STAGE)
                .transform(p -> {
                    //log step
                    LOG.info("flow=stockIntermediateStageChannel, message=rename file: " + p);
                    return p;
                })
                //TODO
                .channel(new NullChannel())
                .get();
    }

    public DefaultSftpSessionFactory createNewSftpSessionFactory(final Branch branch){
        final DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(false);
        factory.setHost(branch.getHost());
        factory.setUser(branch.getUsern());
        factory.setPort(branch.getFtpPort());
        factory.setPassword(branch.getPassword());
        factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);

        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DelegatingSessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> delegatingSFtpSessionFactory(){
        final List<Branch> branchConnections = new ArrayList<>();
        branchRepository.findAll().forEach(branchConnections::add);

        if(branchConnections.isEmpty()){
            return null;
        }

        final Map<Object, SessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry>> factories = new LinkedHashMap<>(10);

        for (Branch br : branchConnections) {
            // create a factory for every key containing server type, url and port
            if (factories.get(br.getId()) == null) {
                factories.put(br.getId(), createNewSftpSessionFactory(br));
            }
        }

        // use the first SF as the default
        return new DelegatingSessionFactory<>(factories, factories.values().iterator().next());
    }

    @Bean
    public RotatingServerAdvice advice(){
        final List<Branch> branchConnections = new ArrayList<>();
        branchRepository.findAll().forEach(branchConnections::add);

        LOG.info("Found " + branchConnections.size() + " server entries for FEFO Stock.");

        final List<RotatingServerAdvice.KeyDirectory> keyDirectories = new ArrayList<>();
        for (final Branch br : branchConnections) {
            keyDirectories
                    .add(new RotatingServerAdvice.KeyDirectory(br.getId().toString(), br.getFolderPath()));
        }

        /*final RotatingServerAdvice rot = new RotatingServerAdvice(
                new MyStandardRotationPolicy(delegatingSFtpSessionFactory(), keyDirectories, true,
                        getFilter(), partnerConfigRepo));
        return rot;*/
        return new RotatingServerAdvice(delegatingSFtpSessionFactory(), keyDirectories, true);

    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you show the code from Spring Integration, but not your own?

Comment: `>Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Session.connect: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset` - the server reset the connection - take a look at the server logs.

Comment: I was able to connect using filezilla normally and the server after a while it disconnects but it is enough time to transfer the file from ftp server to my local, above I pasted my coding correct which you can check

Comment: After checking the server side I could find that the server is FTP and not SFTP which might be the issue here, so I added the FTP maven dependency and it almost have the same classes if I'm not wrong, my main issue that I need help with for now is DelegatingSessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> delegatingSFtpSessionFactory() this takes ChannelSftp,lstEntry but since it is not anymore SFTP what should I replace it with? I could not find the equivalent in FTP, @GaryRussell

Comment: See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ftp.html#_configuring_with_java_configuration_11); it's `<FTPFile>` - the FTP module is virtually identical to the SFTP module from the user perspective.

Comment: <FTPFile> worked perfectly, thanks Gary, I'm left with two issues, 1)Was able to connect to one server while I have two in my Postgres DB tables, it is taking the first one only. 2) If I add a new server or remove old server from DB using HTML interface that I created, the app is not picking the new list automatically, I have to shut it down and re run it again to get the new ones. Any possible solutions for those?@GaryRussell

Comment: I was able to make it work and take what is available in the DB as servers inserted, the only issue I'm left with is at run time if I add or remove server it does not take the new ones saved, I have to stop the app and run it again, is there any solution for that?@GaryRussell